# update existing record or creating new

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to update the database if an entry is already there if not create a new one.

```
def saveprofile(request):
    location = request.POST['location']
    email = request.POST['email']
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        userprofile = UserProfiles(user=request.user)
        if userprofile:
           userprofile.location=location
           userprofile.email=email
           userprofile.save()
           return render_to_response('profile.html',{'pfields':userprofile})
        else:
           userprofile = UserProfiles(user=request.user, location=location, email=email)
           userprofile.save()
           return render_to_response('profile.html',{'pfields':userprofile})
```

It's throwing

> (1062, "Duplicate entry '15' for key 'user_id'")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to use `get` for Django to fetch an existing object instead of creating a new one, which is what your call to `UserProfiles(user=request.user)` is currently doing.

For example:

```
try:
    userprofile = UserProfiles.objects.get(user=request.user)
except DoesNotExist:
    # create object here.
```

See [this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) which is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

First off, while it is true you can handle your forms manually this way, the “right way” to do forms with Django is to use [`django.forms`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/). With this said…

I'll assume your `UserProfiles` model does not contain an explicit primary key. That means, Django creates its own field automatically, called `id`.

Now, when you create a new instance of a model using the constructor, the `id` field will remain empty. It will not fetch anything from the dabase, it will create a new object. Afterwards you assign some values to its fields. Note that the following two are equivalent:

```
userprofile = UserProfiles(user=request.user, location=location, email=email)

# and
userprofile = UserProfiles(user=request.user)
userprofile.location=location
userprofile.email=email
```

since in both cases you just create a new object and set the values of `user`, `location` and `email`.

As soon as you try to save this object, you get an error.

The right way to do this is to first fetch the object from the database:

```
try:
    profile = UserProfiles.objects.get(user=request.user)
except DoesNotExist:
    # Handle the case where a new object is needed.
else:
    # Handle the case where you need to update an existing object.
```

For more information have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/